# No keyword with name found error when running a script where resources are separate

Tags: robotframework

I'm fairly new to automation and I've been doing some training on Pycharm.  My problem is that my script is failing due to 'No keyword with name 'Common.Begin Web Test' found.' when I separate the resources from the actual script.  But when the keywords are included in the script, it's running just fine.

Here's a screenshot of my script.  The first one is where the resources are separate.  The one below is where I'm using just 1 file.

[image: pycharm]

Thanks,
Joan

Comment: Please update your question with the actual, formatted code as text instead of screenshots. Screenshots are difficult to read and if someone wanted to reproduce your issue, you're forcing them to type it all in by hand instead of being able to copy-paste.

Comment: @c32hedge These screenshots are actually required to be able to reproduce the problem because they are showing the directory structure as well. They should be replaced with the formatted code and the with the directory structure.

Comment: @BenceKaulics Thanks for clarifying. The main point was that the OP is much less likely to get help if all they provide are screenshots instead of copyable code--this is an all-too-common problem here. Going ahead and voting to close since the OP never improved the question and appears to be unregistered.

Answer (score 1):

Wrong path when you're importing the resource. Should be ../Resources/Common.robot. The same should be done for Amazon.robot